# Construct set family whose members intersect at even number of points

Tags: combinatorics

F $\subseteq 2^{[n]}$ is a set family. Every member of F has odd size. Every two distinct members of F intersect at even number of points.

1) Show that |F| $\leq$ n

2) Suppose now every member has even size. Show how to construct a family F with |F| $\geq$ $2^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$

Comment: What is n? number of sets?

Comment: I suspect $n$ is the number of distinct elements that are members of members of $F$.

Comment: Check out "Odd town, even town" in Babai and Frankl "Linear algebra methods in Combinatorics"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for 2:  If you group the elements of elements in pairs...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following. We can naturally consider every element $f$ of the family $F$ as an $n$-dimensional vector over the field $\mathbb Z_2$.

1)  In this case any two different vectors of $F$ are orthogonal, so $F$ is a linearly independent set of $n$-dimensional vectors. Then $|F|\le n$.

2) Put $m=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. Define a map $\mathcal F:\mathbb Z_2^m\to Z_2^n$ by putting $$\mathcal F (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m)=(x_1,x_1,x_2,x_2,\dots)$$ (the last coordinate of the image is equal to the zero if $n$ is odd and is equal to $x_m$ if $n$ is even). Then the set $F=\mathcal F(\mathbb Z_2^m)$ has size $2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ and satisfies Condition 2.